# Encryption code that converts strings to integers

Tags: java, for-loop, encryption, methods

The rule for the encryption goes:
Encrypted Digit = letter order * 10 + 4.  For example, A is 14, B is 24, C is 34, etc.

I have to write a program where the user inputs a string and the program outputs said string using the encryption.

Ex.
Input: Flowers 4 You
Output:  64 74 154 244 54 184 194 > 4 > 254 154 214

FYI, I am a very early beginner programmer, I started about 2 months ago and I'm following this course online and need help with this program Ive been stuck on. The spaces must be > and any number input must output as that same number. I've gone far enough to be able to encrypt any letter, but not much else. I preferably want to use a for loop and 2 separate methods for getting a String input, and one for the encryption of the string. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, when asking a code-related question, the very first tag you should add is one for the language you're using. Please [edit] your post to add your code as text, properly formatted as code, and the appropriate language tag.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static String encrypt(int ch, int base) {
    return Integer.toString((ch - base + 1) * 10 + 4);
}

static String encrypt(int ch) {
    if (Character.isLowerCase(ch))
        return encrypt(ch, 'a');
    else if (Character.isUpperCase(ch))
        return encrypt(ch, 'A');
    else if (Character.isDigit(ch))
        return Character.toString(ch);
    else if (Character.isWhitespace(ch))
        return ">";
    return Integer.toString(ch);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    "Flowers 4 You".codePoints()
        .forEach(ch -> System.out.print(encrypt(ch) + " "));
}
```

output:

```
64 124 154 234 54 184 194 > 4 > 254 154 214
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was able to use some parts of your code and implement them in mine. Also helped me understand the math behind it a bit more. Thanks for the help, I greatly appreciate it.